# Double quote in curl request wrongly encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

Maybe my question may not be exactly understandable, but I have a route in my Ruby On Rails website that only contains that I need to retrieve with Curl.
The problem is that the double quotes are encoded, and I don't want them to be like this.

Here is an example(sorry, but the code is confidential):

```rb
# I tried to trim the data, and replace them with a backslash, so the double quote would render as normal, but no success
@data = @data.tr('"', '\"')
```

But the result is :

My name is &quot`;Robert&quot`;

Maybe someone already run run into this issue, but I haven't found anything.
Thanks all !

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want is to mark the @data as HTML.
`<%= @data.html_safe %>`

Comment: Why are you using cURL instead of a HTTP library in the first place?

Comment: Forgot to respond, @javiyu got the right answer, I tried and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help, both of you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add: `<%= @data.html_safe %>`  to my html.erb, Thanks @javijyu for the answer !